# how can we stop executing a function in tcl tkcon GUI?

Tags: tcl

I want to stop function execution on the fly in TkCon GUI. For example I am executing commands and procedures on the TkCon GUI, if I want to stop it on the fly, how can we do that? in linux console we use "ctrl+C". That doesn't work in TkCon GUI.

Comment: In a regular shell, executing code typically runs in a process that is separate from the shell, and hence easy to interrupt without bothering the shell. Tkcon *allows* you to start code in another process, but usually runs it in the same one.

Comment: Ctrl+C is often “Copy” in GUIs…

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you can't. The problem is that the code you're running is in the same thread as the code running the GUI, so the program will not respond to you asking for it to stop. (Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is often used for other purposes, such as copy-to-clipboard.)

However, if you run your program in a separate thread *and keep a handle to that thread*, you can [cancel the execution](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/ThreadCmd/thread.htm#M12) (assuming you have Tcl 8.6). In it's simplest form, you do this:

```
thread::cancel $threadID
```

That will unwind the execution until the code `catch`es the error that gets forced in. (Assuming that the code isn't stopped in something like an external IO call.) You might need to also specify the `-unwind` option if a nest of catches is restarting the looping; when unwinding, the thread will be returned to a well-defined state.

```
thread::cancel -unwind $threadID
```

---

The TkCon GUI doesn't provide this capability for you by default. The simplest way of taking advantage of this is to run your code inside a little master execution context like this:

```
package require Thread

set app_runner [thread::create { thread::wait }]
proc app_eval {args} {
    global app_runner
    thread::send -async $app_runner [concat {*}$args] app_result
}
# Simple receiver for async returns
trace add variable app_result write {apply {args {
    global app_result
    if {$app_result ne ""} {
        puts $app_result
    }
}}}
proc app_cancel {} {
    global app_runner
    thread::cancel $app_runner
}
# Bring the stack trace locally
proc app_handle_error {- info} {
    puts stderr $info
}
thread::errorproc app_handle_error
```

You might also need to set up a background error handler.

I've tested the above with:

```
app_eval {
    while 1 {puts -nonewline .;after 100}
}
app_cancel
```

and it worked nicely. Binding these operations into the GUI is left as an exercise.